# There is no fabric key and secret on the site

Tags: android

I am trying to add fabric to my project but there is no where to provide the api key or secret on fabric.io?

Is this ok?

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Comment: which tutorial or link you have followed?

Answer (score 0):

```
    `Please add maven and dependencies  in project-level build.gradle 
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...

        // Add repository
        maven {
           url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...

        // Check for v3.1.2 or higher
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.2.0'

        // Add dependency
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
       // ...

       // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
       google()  // Google's Maven repository
       // ...
    }
}
```

In your app-level build.gradle,add plugin and dependencies : 
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
    // ...

```
// Check for v11.4.2 or higher
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'

// Add dependency
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'
```

}
     Follow below link https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android  . Add your project into Firebase Console.